# How can I put the index page in root folder with codeiginiter setup

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

Currently , the structure of my server is like this

```
/root/ index.php <==frontend index page
...../backend/index.php <== backend index page
............./system/ <==codeiginiter folder
```

The root folder store all the frontend php files , and is not using  codeiginiter framework. While the backend is stored in a root/backend folder, which is using the codeiginiter framework.

It is very messy and not well-organized , so I tried to re-programm the frontend and also put the frontend and backend in a codeiginiter folder

How should I structure it? And how can I keep root/index.php for front end index page? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to put codeigniter on root and add both front end and back end code inside it.
But still if you are looking for keeping frontend code outside of codeigniter you can do this using htaccess.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried htaccess and it seems redirect is success. Would you mind provide some example of how to store both front end and back end in the same codeigniter folder? Thanks. e.g. briefly what folder and what files I need to concern with ?